# Trying to launch precompiled version of freeradius on 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, freeradius

Hi I have downloaded and configured freeradius successfully on my local mac, and now I am trying to launch it on elastic beanstalk, environment: 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03. It is configured for node.js and I have written a bash startup script (as part of the sample node application amazon provides) to run

```
radiusd -X
```

Unfortunately I get the error

```
./start.sh: line 2: 3.0.11/bin/radiusd: cannot execute binary file
```

Currently my thinking is there is an incompatibility with the environment. I am wondering what the best way to get my configuration of freeradius running on this environment is.

Here is the version of freeradius I am trying to use

```
FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.11, for host i386-apple-darwin15.5.0, built on Jun 30 2016 at 18:36:02
Copyright (C) 1999-2016 The FreeRADIUS server project and contributors
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE
You may redistribute copies of FreeRADIUS under the terms of the
GNU General Public License
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYRIGHT
```

Here's the snippet of node code which I have executing a bash script

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
exec('./start.sh',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

and here is the bash script, **start.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
3.0.11/bin/radiusd -X
```

Comment: In line 2 change ./start.sh to ./start and then try

Comment: I get an error from node if I do that: 'exec error: Error: spawn start.sh ENOENT'

Comment: Just to clarify - ^ that happens on my local machine but it actually works and errors the same as I described in my post on the amazon linux box.